# Windows UI/Application freeze when running 24X7

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have developed one application in C#.net 3.5 and VS 2008, which contain many controls such as tab, textbox, objelistview, gauges, zedgraph.

My application is intended to communicate on serial port and update the data on said ui. To achive this i am using another timer thread.

Its 24X7 running application, but sometime it just freeze and timer thread stops executing automatically, i can see the sceen but can't click anywhere and simply i need to restart application to make it run again.

Please note i dont see application not responding message or likewise, it just simply freeze.

If any one can provide any inputs for the same it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You may have memory leaks or too many uncolsed resources. While your application is freezed see Task Manager and check Memory and CPU usage. They can help you gueesing if too many of RAM is used or if your application consumes too many CPU processing power.

In your application consider disposable objects. Try to dispose them correctly. After opening a serial port don't forget to close it again. Also you can use logging mechanisms to see at what point your application freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing a watchdog using `System.Threading.Timer` and check if thread responsible for communication is responsive. Also, I'm not sure what do you mean by "another timer thread", but again, you should use aforementioned class to track time between datapolls and use callback method.

Please also remember, like *afsharm* said, that you need to free resources you don't use anymore, so either get one handle on your COM port and use it or just release it everytime update has ended.